# Regexp multiple matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a line with the following content:

```
"word1 word2 word3 (compound word) ..."
```

I need a regular expression to separate words into an array, considering the word in parenthesis as a single word and the rest separated by spaces.

Comment: can compound words be nested? I.E. `"word1 (compound (another compound)) word2"`

Comment: no, only one level. list of portuguese words and their translations in parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BARE_WORD     = /([^\(\s]\S*)/
COMPOUND_WORD = /\(([^\)]*)\)/
SCANNER       = /(?:#{BARE_WORD})|(?:#{COMPOUND_WORD})/

def split_bare_and_parenthesized_words str
  str.scan(SCANNER).flat_map(&:compact)
end

split_bare_and_parenthesized_words "word1 word2 word3 (compound word) ..."
#=> ["word1", "word2", "word3", "compound word", "..."]
```

This implementation won't handle nested parens.  Such conditions are intrinsically hard with a regular language.

(EDIT: @DavidUnric points out OP implies he doesn't want the parens in the result. So we add captures and flat_map to reduce to the alternate which matched.)

Comment: There should be no parens in the result, just the content they are surrounding.

Answer (score 0):

As split can also take an RegExp it's easy to split string as requested:

```
irb> "word1 word2 word3 (compound word)".split(/ *\((.*)\) *| /)
=> ["word1", "word2", "word3", "compound word"]
```

ie. split by parens surrounded by arbitrary count of spaces or by a single space.

Answer (score 0):

```
"word1 word2 word3 (compound word) ...".scan(/\(.*?\)|\S+/)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/WtfCA/

```
function test(str) {
    var bracketStr = str.match(/\([a-z]*\s[a-z]*\)/g, "temp")[0];
    var temp = str.replace(/\([a-z]*\s[a-z]*\)/g, "temp").split(" ");
    var final = temp.join("+").replace(/temp/, bracketStr).split("+");
    console.log(final);
}
```